# Wget command that will Fetch a specific version of a snapshot version of an artifact

Tags: maven, nexus

I would like to provide a Wget command that will always Fetch a specific version of a snapshot version of an artifact.

Meaning  Let's say I have Version **14.00-SNAPSHOT** inside my Nexus snapshot repository,  and inside this version I have 3 snapshot artifacts,
Now I want to get one of those artifacts and download it VIA **wget** command,
I know how I can get the Latest version (by default it takes the latest and also I can use v=LATEST) but I want to be able to choose which version that I want.

This is the command I use:

```
wget "NexusUrl/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=%nexusRepository%&v=%NexusArtifactVersion%&g=%NexusGroupID%&a=%NexusArtifactName%&e=zip"
```

Looking at the METADATA file it looks like I don't have the way to choose:

[image]

Comment: You probably can get an exact version by specifying it with v=14.00-20161213.043528-196 PS: Please don't use images for XML pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you should be able to use v= to accomplish this. A lot more information on this call in general is available here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465488-How-can-I-retrieve-a-snapshot-if-I-don-t-know-the-exact-filename-

For the record, depending on a snapshot is not advised, they tend to get cleaned up by Repo Managers.